# Wmii on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, window-manager

I installed the quantal wmii deb package, but when I try to log into Wmii it is completely unresponsive.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested, the solution for me was as follows:

Download this package(no other package worked for me, I tried them all):

https://code.google.com/p/wmii/downloads/detail?name=wmii%2Bixp-3.9.2.tbz

Untar it and run:

```
$ make
```

There will most likely be lots of dependency issues.  Some of them I found .deb packages for by searching the package names in Google, others Synaptic was able to locate.  If you already have a similar package installed to the one that contains the missing file, install the "-dev" version as well.

Then run:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Shouldn't be any issues there.  To run Wmii inside your current GUI, create a .xinitrc file in your home directory and add the following line:

```
until wmii; do :; done
```

Doing this might cause your next login attempt to fail, or rather, after successful login you will be presented with the login screen again.  Solve as follows:

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
$ * login with username and password *
$ sudo chown yourusername:yourusername ~/.Xauthority
Ctrl + Alt + F7
```

You should be able to login as normal now.

You can now open a Wmii session by running:

```
$ sudo startx
```

If, like me, you want to add Wmii as an option at login, create the following file:

```
$ sudo emacs /usr/share/xsessions/wmii.desktop
```

with the contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Wmii
Comment=Window manager improved 3
Exec=wmii
Icon=wmii.png
Type=XSession
```

and you're good to go!

Helpful links:

https://github.com/sunaku/wmii